# Magento : TypeError: source is not an object properties = Object.keys(source);

Tags: magento-enterprise, prototype-js

[image]I am getting this error in my console what is cause of this error??? it is in prototype.js.I am using magento enterprise edition

Thanks,

Comment: if anyone knows the solution to fix this kindly reply back

Comment: still no luck !!! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer Add

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/scripts.js</name></action>
```

in your theme layout(page.xml) will resolve this issue

Comment: This solution is not working

Comment: Did u try in your theme folder ?? coz it is working for me !!

Comment: Yes I tried and js is visible in the source.